# ASP.Net accessing model parameters within function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `.cshtml` file which I am using the model:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVCTest.Models.Test>
```

The model contains the parameter `Date` (among other parameters). I access this value when creating a table:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>
        ...
```

I have a function in my code `NotTested` and I want to pass the `item.Date` value into the function as one of the arguments:

```
<script>
         document.onload = NotTested("Site 001", item.Date);

         function NotTested(SiteId, TestDate) { ... }
</script>
```

The problem is two-fold. 1) I know that the Date is part of the model in this view so that it is present `onload` when the function is called, but 2) the `model` is out of context in the `<script>` section of code.

I know that `item` is not present `onload` since this is is only transient for the for loop. I have just used `item.Date` as a placeholder argument.

How do I get access to this when calling the function?

Comment: Are you wanting to call this function for each item in your model?

Comment: No. Just the Date item and only when the form loads

Comment: I meant that you have a loop - so did you want to pass the `Date` property for each item in the collection?

Comment: If so there are a number a ways you could do this - e.g. assign the model to a javascript variable = refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730055/jquery-how-to-traverse-iterate-over-a-list-of-object/30730172#30730172), but it would be easiest just to add a class name (say) `<td class="date">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>` element and use `$('.date').each(function() { NotTested("Site 001", $(this).text()) });`

Comment: The `Date` item is actually the same because of model I am loading in. It is the "other" parameters which change in when looping through the table. That is why I can call this `onload` and know that the `Date` is the same.

Comment: If the date does not vary, then you could assign it to a `ViewBag` property and use `var date = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Date))'); NotTested("Site 001", date);` Note also you should wrap the script in [$.document.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) - not using `document.onload`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - you strike again! Thank you this works perfectly :-) If you want to write this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, property `Date` is the same for each item in your collection, so you can assign it to a javascript variable using

```
var date = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model[0].Date))');
```

or in the controller, assign in to `ViewBag.Date = yourDate;` and in the script

```
var date = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Date))');
```

You can then use call the function using

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var date = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Date))');
    NotTested("Site 001", date);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. FYI I used the `ViewBag.Date` method

Answer (score 0):

Assign a css class to the date item and use jquery to select the date items based on the css class as following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "mySiteIDClass" } })

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "myDateClass" } })

<script>
         document.onload = NotTested($(".mySiteIDClass"), $(".myDateClass"));

         function NotTested(SiteIds, TestDates) { //loop through date items }
</script>
```