# Get ViewData in View JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I have a Generic List and I'm passing it as ViewData from my Controller to my .aspx View.
I need to get and iterate it with a Jquery Script.

How could I make this script works?

Regards

```
success: function (result) {

 var myArray = new Array();
 var myArray = '<%: ViewData["List"] %>';

 for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
 alert(i);
 }
```

Comment: What is in your ViewData["List"]

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to traverse / Iterate over a list of object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730055/jquery-how-to-traverse-iterate-over-a-list-of-object)

Comment: dont forget to upvote or make as answer if it worked for you...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this , push items of list view to the array of javascript, wrap below code in script tag

```
--script tag--
var jList = new Array();
@foreach (var item in ViewData["List"] as List<String>)
   {
       @:jList.push('@item'); // That will work if its a one letter string but It doesnt know that its a string untill you use ''
 }
--script tag--
```

Comment: I guess you can be more clear on that whether the op has to write it in Scripts or in the html part . For that Answer you may be getting  "list doesnot exists in the current context" error as I doubt that variable list will detected inside foreach

Comment: @Vivekh - may be you are correct i learning mvc and got syntax like this only

Comment: Okay but if you write this var jList = new Array(); in  Html Markup  it will print as it as so you should put that in code block or @

Comment: No I dont think so because it wont be able to detect that jList is an javascript variable because as u used foreach it will assume that jList is a c# variable untill you specify it is a javascript variable by using @: or <text></text>

Comment: @Vivekh - updated as per example i missed @: ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{ List<string> ss = (List<string>)ViewData["List"];}
    var myArray = [
    @for (int i = 0; i < ss.Count; i++)
    {
        @: @(ss[i]),
    }
    ]
</script>
```

**my syntax for razor view**(you can do it for classic)

Comment: I think you might have to write  @: '@(ss[i])', instead of  @: @(ss[i]), to get it as an array of strings

Comment: Tried before but I get syntax error as unexpected token @

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you are using just a list of strings then

this will do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
@{List<string> listFromController = (List<string>)ViewData["List"];}
    var myArray = [
    @for (int i = 0; i < listFromController.Count; i++)
    {
        @: '@(listFromController[i])',
    }
    ]
});
```

But if you are passing list of another type rather than string like an student Employee or a user you will need the following

> Please use the appropriate class that you have passed and the
>   properties suppose "UserName" could be "FirstName" "EmpId" or what ever

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        @{ var listFromController = (List<KnockoutJSWebApi.Models.LoginViewModel>)ViewData["list"];}
        var totalArray = [];
            @for (int i = 0; i < listFromController.Count; i++)
            {

                <text>
        var thisArray= {
            'username': '@(listFromController[i].UserName)',
            'password': '@(listFromController[i].Password)'
        };
        totalArray.push(thisArray);
            </text>
            }
 });
```

Aspx View Engine syntax:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            <% List<string> listFromController = (List<string>)ViewData["List"]; %>
            var myArray = [
             <% for (int i = 0; i < listFromController.Count; i++){ %>

                '<%: listFromController[i] %>',
              <% } %>
            ]
            debugger;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Invalid Character @Vivekh

Comment: could you please send me the code with aspx syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
I used a JsonResult method in my Controller and returned the needed values as:

```
Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

With that, I don't need to iterate the values because I assign them as datasource to my DropDownList control.

```
$("#Generic_FK").data("DropDownList").dataSource.data(result);
```

Hope to help other people with the same issue!

Comment: are you using Telerik

Comment: Then you have missed several tags in your Question. you need to be more clear. you should have tagged aspx view engine and telerik also

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side**

```
  public class users
        {        
            public string name{ get; set; }
        }

        // in your controller code
        ViewData["list"] = new List<users>(new users[] { new users() 
                          { name="prasad"}, new users() {name="raja"}});
```

**Client Side**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var myitems=JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.ViewData["list"]))');

    $.each(myitems, function(index, item) {
      var name = item.name;
    });
});
</script>
```

i hope this may help you

Comment: It gives me this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token @    0:1