# MVC - comparison of 2 viewdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, html.textboxfor

I have 2 viewdata, `ViewData["product"]` & `ViewData["ProductRetailPriceList"] values` assigned in controller reading from `database` as follow:

```
 var product = db.ProductTbls.ToList();
   List<SelectListItem> productlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
   List<SelectListItem> ProductRetailPriceList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach(ProductTbl item in product)
        {
            productlist.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item.ProductName,
                    Value = item.ProductID.ToString()
                }
                );

            ProductRetailPriceList.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item.RetailUnitRentPrice.ToString(),
                    Value = item.ProductID.ToString()

                }); 
ViewData["product"]  = productlist;
ViewData["ProductRetailPriceList"] = ProductRetailPriceList;
```

I assign the value of the `ViewData["product"]` to a `dropdownlist` in the view as follow:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductNamevm, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["product"], new { id = "productname" })
```

For the price textbox I created it as follow:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductPrice, new { id = "productprice" })
```

I want to write a javascript that will allow me to change the value of product price textbox when I change the value the product name `dropdownlist`
what I got so far is the following:

```
 $("#productname").change(function ()
                {
                    getprice();
                })



                function getprice()
                {
                    var productname = $("#productname").val();
                    var clienttype = $("#clienttype").val();


                    if (clienttype  == "Retail")
                    {

                        foreach (productname == ViewData["ProductRetailPriceList"])
                        {
                            var x = ViewData["ProductRetailPriceList"];
                            $("#productprice").val(x);
                        }

                    }   
                }
```

FYI `ClientType` is a `dropdownlist` I dont have issues with.
When I inspect in the browser the code doesnt go inside the foreach.
can someone guide me how to compare ViewData["ProductRetailPriceList"] to the selected ViewData["product"] so I can assign it to the price textbox.
Thanks.

Comment: First `ViewData["ProductRetailPriceList"]` should not be a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (you are not using it in a dropdownlist - it should just be a collection of the `ProductID` and `RetailUnitRentPrice`). Then you need to convert it to a javascript array - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730055/jquery-how-to-traverse-iterate-over-a-list-of-object/30730172#30730172) and find the price based on the `ProductID`

Comment: And why are you assigning it to a textbox? - it should be display only (user should not be able to edit it)

Comment: ok got your point on IEnumerable<SelectListItem> just to clarify I will create a ViewModel that will include ProductID and RetailUnitRentPriceand then assign it to array in javascript

Comment: BTW it was a client requirement to allow the user to change the price on the spot for certain customer so I kept enabled  and when the user submit the form the data is inerted to a different table